# Using ipython exclamation point outside of ipython

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to use the useful `!` call-to-shell feature of ipython in regular python script, i.e. I want the following code:

```
for i in range(5):
  !echo {i}
```

To work in an in-house python module that can be imported (thus simply using `!` will not work).

I've tried using subprocess but wasn't able to get the output of the shell run into the Jupyter notebook, where most of our scripts are running at.

So, what I'm looking for is using `!` functionality as an IPython import some how..

Comment: Any updates....?